# Google ML Engine - Scikit-Learn Models

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

Looking at the documentation for ML Engine, it looks like they accept training and prediction services for Scikit Learn models.

Is it possible to train non Scikit Learn models that is wrapped with Mixins to transform into a Scikit Learn Interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ml-engine currently has support for this in alpha, however, it's currently broken for some custom models.

Furthermore logs for version creates for models is not visible. Last time I talked to GCP ml services people, they said they will add stackdriver functionality soon.

EDIT:

Since this answer was first given at Sep, 2018, now is Dec, 2018, and the logging functionality is still not available. I'm wrapping Facebook's Prophet in a custom model, and training works but versioning is still broken.

Versioning Error Message:

```
Create Version failed. Internal error happened.
```